# Como adicionar e pesquisar produtos do BD com JSON em campos dinamicos HTML?

Tags: javascript, json

Pessoal não consigo obter valores da pesquisa de realizo com JSON e banco de dados após adicionar nova linha de produto dinâmica com JavaScript.

Formulário HTML, o produto é pesquisa pelo código:

```
<form id="adicionarformProdutos" method"post" action"" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <a href="#" id="adicionarProduto">Adicionar Faixa</a>      
    <fieldset class="fieldsetProduto">
        <legend>Produto 1</legend>
        <div class="produtos">
            <label for="codProduto1">Código:</label><input type="text" id="codProduto1" size="5" name="codProduto[1]" />
            <label for="nomeProduto1">Nome:</label> <input type="text" id="nomeProduto1" size="9" disabled name="nomeProduto[1]" />
            <label for="qtProduto1">Qt.:</label> <input type="number" min="1" max="999" size="1" id="qtProduto1" name="qtProduto[1]" onblur="calcValor()" />
            <label for="valorProduto1">Valor und. R$:</label> <input type="text" id="valorProduto1" disabled name="valorProduto[1]" size="6" onkeypress="mascara(this,float)" />
        </div>
     </fieldset>
</form>
```

Trecho JSON que realiza busca dos produtos e preenche as demais variáveis:

```
//-----------------------------------------------------
//Funcao: functionjson
//Autor: Rafael Assmann <rafael@emperiumcode.com>
//Sinopse: Json para capturar código do produto e reali
//zar a busca no banco de dados e preencher os demais campos deste produto
//Parametro:
//   codProduto[] : código do produto digitado para pesquisa
//Retorno: nomeProduto[], qtProduto[] e valorProduto[] : informações do BD
//-----------------------------------------------------
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name='codProduto[1]']").blur(function(){
         var nomeProduto = $("input[name='nomeProduto[1]']");
         var qtProduto = $("input[name='qtProduto[1]']");
         var valorProduto = $("input[name='valorProduto[1]']");

         $( nomeProduto ).val('Carregando...');
         $( qtProduto ).val('Carregando...');
         $( valorProduto ).val('Carregando...');

             $.getJSON(
                 'function.php',
                 { codProduto: $( this ).val() },
                 function( json ) 
                 {
                      $( nomeProduto ).val( json.nomeProduto );
                      $( qtProduto ).val("1");
                      $( valorProduto ).val( json.valorProduto);
                 }
             );
     });
});
```

Trecho onde adiciona mais produtos, que no qual a interação JSON não funciona:

```
$(function () {
    var i = 1;
    $("#adicionarProduto").click(function () {
        i++;
        novoProduto = $(".fieldsetProduto:first").clone();
        novoProduto.find("input").each(function () {
            $(this).val("")
        });

        $("#adicionarformProdutos").append("
        " + novoProduto.html().replace(/1/g, i) + "")
    });
});
```

Insert no banco de dados, OBS: as variaveis que são alimentadas pelo JSON parecem estar vazias:

```
<?php
$Ficha = filter_input(INPUT_GET,'id');
?>

<div id="painelcadastro2" align="center">
<?php   if (isset($_GET['cadastra']) && $_GET['cadastra'] == 'add') {
  $datacompra = implode("-", array_reverse(explode("/",$_GET['datacompra'])));
  $nomeProduto = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'nomeProduto1');
  $qtProduto = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'qtProduto1');
  $valorProduto = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'valorProduto1');
  $parcelas = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'select_parcelas');
  $entrada = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'entrada');
  $total = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'total');
  $pagamento = "CREDIARIO";
  $cadastra = mysql_query("INSERT INTO t_cadcontratos (Ficha, DataContrato, QuantParcelas, ValorContrato, Entrada, Saldo, DescricaoProduto, QuantProdutos, FormaPagamento) 
                          VALUES ('$Ficha', '$datacompra', '$parcelas', '$valorProduto', '$entrada', '$total', '$nomeProduto', '$qtProduto', '$pagamento')");
  if($cadastra == '1') {
        echo "Venda Crediário realizada com sucesso !";
  }else{
        echo "Erro ao realizar a venda Crediário, tente novamente !";
  }
}
?>
```

Function.php

```
<?php
/**
 * função que devolve em formato JSON os dados do cliente
 */
function retorna( $nome, $db )
{
    $sql = "SELECT `identProduto`, `codProduto`, `qtProduto`, `nomeProduto`, `valorProduto` FROM `t_estoque` WHERE `codProduto` = '{$nome}' ";

         $query = $db->query( $sql );

         $arr = Array();
         if( $query->num_rows )
         {
             while( $dados = $query->fetch_object() )
             {
                 $arr['nomeProduto'] = $dados->nomeProduto;
                 $arr['qtProduto'] = $dados->qtProduto;
                 $arr['valorProduto'] = $dados->valorProduto;
             }
         }else{
             $arr['nomeProduto'] = 'produto não encontrado';
         }
         if($arr['qtProduto'] == 0)
            $arr['nomeProduto'] = 'sem estoque';

         return json_encode( $arr );
    }

/* só se for enviado o parâmetro, que devolve os dados */
if( isset($_GET['codProduto']) )
{
    $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'buchm613_buchmann');
    echo retorna( filter ( $_GET['codProduto'] ), $db );
}

function filter( $var ){
    return $var;//a implementação desta, fica a cargo do leitor
}
```

Como posso proceder para preencher os campos adicionados dinamicamente através do trecho JavaScript acima?

Comment: Editei a pergunta pra melhorar a identação do último código - que estava difícil de ler - mas mantive a quebra de linha indevida dentro da string, para não alterar o código original. Seu código está assim mesmo? Se sim, não deu erro de compilação no JavaScript?

Comment: A propósito, essa linha `$("#adicionarformProdutos").append("" + novoProduto.html().replace(/1/g, i) + "")` - mesmo corrigida - altera indevidamente várias propriedades do seu código, como o atributo `min`. Veja [esse exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/srL0qa43/), cada vez que se adiciona um novo produto sua quantidade mínima fica igual ao índice do produto (i.e. o produto 4 tem quantidade mínima 4, o 5 tem quantidade mínima 5, etc).

Comment: Entendido a parte do quantidade minima, obrigado mgibsonbr, vou verificar uma solução para isso mas meu problema esta quando adiciono novos índices de produto, meu jSON simplesmente não funciona, sei que crio nome de inputs diferentes quando adiciono mas não sei o tratamento correto no trecho JSON para realizar a pesquisa no BD, tens alguma ideia?

Comment: Sim, estou escrevendo uma resposta agora, em breve eu posto.

Comment: ok! por enquanto apenas alterei o input number para text por quanto do minimo da quantidade, não tenho porque utilizar o tipo number neste momente, aguardo retorno!

Comment: olá @mgibsonbr neste exemplo do jsFiddle que mencionou abaixo para adicionar campos (faixas) sabes me informar como posso fazer para remove-las?

Comment: O que eu costumo fazer é colocar junto do elemento criado um link ou botão para removê-lo, e uma função `click` que - por ter uma referência para o elemento - pode simplesmente chamar `novoElemento.detach()` (ou `remove`). Mas no seu caso, com todos esses códigos numéricos que se incrementam a cada clonagem, fica um pouquinho mais complicado... Infelizmente, não tenho nada a sugerir a respeito. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O seu código `$("input[name='codProduto[1]']").blur(...)` apenas atribui um *handler* pro evento `blur` dos elementos que **já estão** na página desde o princípio - ou seja, o primeiro produto. Se você quer fazer isso para um novo produto, eu sugiro utilizar o método [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (ou `live`, se for uma versão muito antiga do jQuery).

Em primeiro lugar, acrescente uma classe ao seu `input` para facilitar sua seleção (por alguma razão que desconheço, o seletor `.produtos > input:first` não está funcionando como eu esperava):

```
<input class="codigoProduto" type="text" id="codProduto1" size="5" name="codProduto[1]" />
```

Segundo, quando for clonar não pegue somente o `elemento.html` (esse seria o `innerHTML`). Em vez disso, atualize o HTML e depois adicione o próprio elemento (tomando cuidado para não substituir demais, [como apontado nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35486/como-adicionar-e-pesquisar-produtos-do-bd-com-json-em-campos-dinamicos-html#comment68915_35486), mas aqui vou ignorar isso):

```
//$("#adicionarformProdutos").append("" + novoProduto.html().replace(/1/g, i) + "")
novoProduto.html(novoProduto.html().replace(/1/g, i));
$("#adicionarformProdutos").append(novoProduto)
```

Terceiro, use o `on`:

```
$(document).on("blur", ".codigoProduto", function(){
```

Por fim, selecione os elementos corretos para atualizar - não apenas o primeiro:

```
 var parent = $(this).parent();
 var nomeProduto = parent.children("input:eq(1)");
 var qtProduto = parent.children("input:eq(2)");
 var valorProduto = parent.children("input:eq(3)");
```

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srL0qa43/1/). Gostaria também de mencionar que não é necessário usar o operador `$` novamente em `$( nomeProduto )`, etc, pois eles já são objetos jQuery. Mas também não atrapalha...

Comment: Muito bom @mgibsonbr, obrigado! mas no momento que eu altero por "$(document).on("blur", ".codigoProduto", function(){" não consigo mais pesquisar os produtos, eu utilizo o JQuery da seguinte forma:

"<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>"

Comment: @RafaelAssmann O `on` só está disponível a partir do jQuery 1.7. Se não pode atualizar seu jQuery. tente substituir a chamada do `on` por `$(document).delegate(".codigoProduto", "blur", function() {` e veja se resolve. Há também o `live`, mas se o `delegate` funcionar é melhor assim.

Comment: Funcionou sim, estava tentando com .delegate mas os parâmetros nas ordens erradas, tudo certo agora @mgibsonbr muito obrigado novamente! se for possível favor de uma atenção para esta outra pergunta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35489/como-tratar-select-por-id-de-clientes-entre-duas-p%C3%A1ginas-php/35494#35494 ++

Comment: @RafaelAssmann Foi mal, eu entendo de jQuery mas não sei nada de PHP... De todo modo, me parece que a resposta que você já recebeu lá está no caminho certo: se a página A mandou pra página B, você precisa preservar os conteúdos de A de alguma forma. Repetindo-os num *hidden input* em B é um meio; colocando-os em um cookie é outro. Os detalhes (e a segurança) de cada alternativa vai depender do seu caso particular.

Comment: perfeito, vou seguir nesta linha, novamente obrigado!

Comment: cara fui gravar no banco de dados os valores capturados no JSON e os inputs parecem estar vazios, adicionei o trecho em que faço o insert no banco!

Comment: @RafaelAssmann Que eu saiba, não é o `id` do input que é enviado num POST, e sim o `name` (eu até achei que essa era a razão pra esses nomes "doidos" que você estava colocando - `codProduto[1]` etc). Além disso, se você está submetendo o formulário via POST você tem que buscar as variáveis no [`$_POST`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.post.php), não no `$_GET`. Eu *acho* (de novo, não conheço PHP, mas já vi uns códigos por aí) que com os `name`s que você está usando você vai receber no seu servidor algo como um array chamado `codProduto`, outro chamado `nomeProduto`, etc.

Comment: P.S. Se o problema persistir, sugiro abrir uma outra pergunta para isso, antes que esta se torne uma ["pergunta camaleão"](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1684/215)... :)

Comment: tranquilo @mgibsonbr teu comentário me deu uma ideia e funcionou tudo, abraço!

Comment: Voltando ao JSON, quando realizo pesquisa e o produto não é encontrado os meus campos html ainda permanecem escrito "Carregando...", fiz um tratamento no arquivo function.php mas não consegui resolver, podes me ajudar? Adicionei o function.php na pergunta.

Answer (score 3):

Sugiro uma nova abordagem pois como o [@mgibsonbr referiu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35486/como-adicionar-e-pesquisar-produtos-do-bd-com-json-em-campos-dinamicos-html#comment68915_35486) da maneira que está vai mudar propriedades que não quer.

Crie uma função que lhe retorna o clone com o numero de produto certo.

Algo como:

```
function novoProduto(nr){
    var html = '<fieldset class="fieldsetProduto">' +
        '<legend>Produto ' + nr + '</legend>' +
        '<div class="produtos">' +
        '<label for="codProduto' + nr + '">Código:</label><input type="text" id="codProduto' + nr + '" size="5" name="codProduto[' + nr + ']" />' +
        '<label for="nomeProduto' + nr + '">Nome:</label> <input type="text" id="nomeProduto' + nr + '" size="9" dis' + nr + 'bled name="nomeProduto[' + nr + ']" />' +
        '<label for="qtProduto' + nr + '">Qt.:</label> <input type="number" min="1" max="999" size="1" id="qtProduto1" name="qtProduto[' + nr + ']" onblur="calcValor()" />' +
        '<label for="valorProduto' + nr + '">Valor und. R$:</label> <input type="text" id="valorProduto' + nr + '" disabled name="valorProduto[' + nr + ']" size="6" onkeypress="mascara(this float)" />' +
        '</div>' +
        '</fieldset>';
    return html;
}
```

Aí sempre que quiser um elemento novo só precisa fazer `novoProduto(i)`.

Uma outra sugestão e relacionada com a manutenção do código é: em vez de usar `$("input[name='codProduto[1]']").blur(function(){` etc... que o vai obrigar a ter um código semelhante para cada novo produto, sugiro usar assim:

```
function carregarJSON() {
    var index = this.id.slice(-1);
    var self = this;
    var nomeProduto = $("input[name='nomeProduto[" + index + "]']");
    var qtProduto = $("input[name='qtProduto[" + index + "]']");
    var valorProduto = $("input[name='valorProduto[" + index + "]']");

    $(nomeProduto).val('Carregando...');
    $(qtProduto).val('Carregando...');
    $(valorProduto).val('Carregando...');

    $.getJSON(
        'function.php', {
        codProduto: self.value
    },

    function (json) {
        $(nomeProduto).val(json.nomeProduto);
        $(qtProduto).val(nr);
        $(valorProduto).val(json.valorProduto);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("blur", "input[name^='codProduto[']", carregarJSON);
});
```

Repare também que retirei o `this` dentro do $getJSON. Se não estou em erro o `this`aí não ponta mais para o seu input mas sim para a função jQUery.

E já agora, sugestão de optimização também aqui:

```
$(function () {
    var i = 1;
    $("#adicionarProduto").click(function () {
        i++;
        $("#adicionarformProdutos").append(novoProduto(i))
    });
});
```

Se mantiver o código que tem aqui, julgo que não precisa do `.each()`. Basta:

```
novoProduto.find("input").val("") //não precisa do .each() aqui
```

Comment: +1 pela excelente sugestão de refatoração, mas receio que isso não resolva o problema do AP - repare que o `blur` somente é acrescentado aos elementos que **já estão** na página, não naqueles que são acrescentados dinamicamente.

Comment: @mgibsonbr verdade. Esquecí esse detalhe, vou corrigir. Vi agora a sua resposta também. ++

Comment: Corrigido ^, usei delegação para esses inputs: `$(document).on("blur", "input[name^='codProduto[']", carregarJSON);`