# Como tratar select por ID de clientes entre duas páginas PHP

Tags: php

Pessoal quando eu seleciono um cliente e após isso entro na página de seus crediarios e tendo realizar novo cadastro de crediario o ID deste cliente se perde, como posso tratar isto?

arquivo para selecionar clientes -> clientes.php

```
<div id="painelcadastro2">
<div align="center">
<?php
$sql = "SELECT Ficha, Snome FROM t_cadclientes ORDER BY Ficha ASC, Snome ASC";
$resultado = mysql_query($sql)
            or die (mysql_error());
if(@mysql_num_rows($resultado) == 0)
            echo ("Cliente não encontrado(a) !");
?>

<form id="form2" name="form2" method"post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div align="center">
  <table border="0" align="center">
      <tr>
        <td><label>
          <select name="id" id="id">
            <option value="-1" selected="selected">Selecione um cliente</option>
            <?php 
    while($linha=mysql_fetch_array($resultado)) {
        $id = $linha[0];
        $Snome = $linha[1];
?>
            <option value="<?php echo $id;?>"><?php echo $Snome;  ?></option>
<?php
    }
?>
          </select>
          </label></td>
          <tr>
        <label>
          <input type=image src="../images/vendas_crediarioOver.png" onMouseOver="this.src='../images/vendas_crediario.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='../images/vendas_crediarioOver.png'" title="Venda Crediário" style="border:0;" name="vendas_crediario" id="vendas_crediario" value="vendas_crediario" formaction="vendas_crediario.php" />
          </label>
      </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

arquivo onde verifico os crediarios deste cliente e posso adicionar um novo -> vendas_crediario.php

```
    <div id="painelcadastro">
    <div align="center">
    <?php
    $Ficha = $_GET['id'];
    $selecionacliente = mysql_query("SELECT Ficha, Snome FROM t_cadclientes WHERE Ficha = '$Ficha'");
      if($selecionacliente == ''){
        echo "Erro ao Selecionar, tente novamente !";
      }else{  
        while($res_idcliente = mysql_fetch_array($selecionacliente)){
        $id = $res_idcliente['Ficha'];
        $Snome = $res_idcliente['Snome'];
    ?> 
    <br /><br />

    Ficha Número: <?php echo $Ficha ?><br />
    Nome do Cliente: <?php echo $Snome?>
    <br /><br />

             <?php
    $sql = "SELECT NumContrato, DataContrato FROM t_cadcontratos WHERE Ficha = '$Ficha'";
    $resultadocontratos = mysql_query($sql)
          or die (mysql_error());
    if(@mysql_num_rows($resultadocontratos) == 0)
          echo ("Este cliente não possui contratos !");
    ?><br />
    <form id="form2" name="form2" method"post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div align="center">
      <table border="0" align="center">
          <tr>
            <td><label>
              <select name="id" id="id">
                <option value="-1" selected="selected">Selecione um contrato</option>
                <?php 
      while($linha=mysql_fetch_array($resultadocontratos)) {
        $NumContrato = $linha[0];
        $DataContrato = $linha[1];
    ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $NumContrato;?>">Contrato: <?php echo $NumContrato;?> | Data da Compra: <?php echo date("d/m/Y", strtotime($DataContrato));?></option> <br /><br />
    <?php
      }
    ?>        
     </select>
              </label></td>
              <tr>
            <label>
              <input type="hidden" name="apaga" value="delete" />
              <input type=image src="../images/excluirOver.png" onMouseOver="this.src='../images/excluir.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='../images/excluirOver.png'" title="Excluir Contrato" style="border:0;" name="delete" id="delete" value="Excluir" />
              <input type=image src="../images/editarOver.png" onMouseOver="this.src='../images/editar.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='../images/editarOver.png'" title="Editar Contrato" style="border:0;" name="Alterar" id="Alterar" value="Alterar" formaction="editar_contrato.php" />
              <input type=image src="../images/imprimirOver.png" onMouseOver="this.src='../images/imprimir.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='../images/imprimirOver.png'" title="Imprimir Contrato" style="border:0;" name="Imprimir" id="Imprimir" value="Imprimir"  formaction="imprimir_contrato.php" />
              </label>
          </tr>
</table><td>
 <?php
  }
}
?>
<input type=image src="../images/cadastrarOver.png" onMouseOver="this.src='../images/cadastrar.png'" value="<?php echo $id?>" onMouseOut="this.src='../images/cadastrarOver.png'" title="Cadastrar" style="border:0;" name="cadastro" id="cadastro" value="cadastro"  formaction="cadastro_contrato.php" />
</div><!--fechando div painelcadastro-->
```

arquivo para adicionar crediario para o cliente -> cadastro_crediario.php

Ficha Número:

```
<div id="painelcadastro2" align="center">
<?php   if (isset($_GET['cadastra']) && $_GET['cadastra'] == 'add') {
  $datacompra = implode("-", array_reverse(explode("/",$_GET['datacompra'])));
  $nomeProduto = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nomeProduto1');
  $qtProduto = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'qtProduto1');
  $valorProduto = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'valorProduto1');
  $parcelas = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'select_parcelas');
  $entrada = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'entrada');
  $total = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'total');
  $pagamento = "CREDIARIO";
  $ficha = $_GET['cadastro'];
  $cadastra = mysql_query("INSERT INTO t_cadcontratos (Ficha, NumContrato,DataContrato, QuantParcelas, ValorContrato, Entrada, Saldo, DescricaoProduto, QuantProdutos, FormaPagamento) 
                          VALUES ('$ficha', '$datacompra', '$parcelas', '$valorProduto', '$entrada', '$total', UPPER('$nomeProduto'), '$qtProduto', '$pagamento')");
  if($cadastra == '1') {
        echo "Venda Crediário realizada com sucesso !";
  }else{
        echo "Erro ao realizar a venda Crediário, tente novamente !";
  }
}
?>
```

Ao clicar em cadastro no formulário que não inseri aqui o valor de $_GET['cadastro']; que seria do ID do cliente se perde na hora da inserção no banco de dados.

Answer (score 3):

Cara, eu não sei se eu entendi bem, mas parece que você quer enviar o ID do cliente da página "vendas_crediario.php" para "cadastro_crediario.php". Se for isso, basta você criar um input hidden contendo o id do cliente. Ficaria algo assim:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $Ficha?>" name="cadastro" />
```

Comment: é exatamente isso, lembrando que ja trouxe o ID do cliente de outra página, me desculpe faltou o fim da página vendas_crediario que seria o botão separada para enviar o ID <input type=image src="../images/cadastrarOver.png" onMouseOver="this.src='../images/cadastrar.png'" value="<?php echo $id?>" onMouseOut="this.src='../images/cadastrarOver.png'" title="Cadastrar" style="border:0;" name="cadastro" id="cadastro" value="cadastro"  formaction="cadastro_contrato.php" />

Comment: Passando o ID desta forma eu conseguir imprimir o valor normalmente, mas quando vou adicionar no BD após preencher os campos eu perco esta variavel, tens alguma ideia?